# How do you set Django environment variables with venv on linux?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I've tried using Python's os, manually typing the variables into the terminal, and using a .env file to set my environment variables but always get

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

#### Python

```py
# env.py
import os
os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] = '<my secret key>'
```

#### Inside .env

```sh
export SECRET_KEY=<my secret key>
```

#### settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
```

Running my python script will not make the environment variables persist.

---

- Ubuntu 20.04.02
- Django 3.1
- Using VSCode

I have double checked the correct venv activated.

What am I doing wrong! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django itself does not read `.env` file. The best way, to enable it is to use [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package

Modify you settings.py

```
import environ
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
```

And .env file

```
SECRET_KEY=your-secret-key
```

Answer (score 0):

try if in settings.py exist:

```
SECRET_KEY = '<my secret key>'
```

Comment: File "/home/alex/dev/djangoAws/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 189, in __init__raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.